# Unable to instantiate application com.company.app.MainApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException React Native Expo

Tags: java, android, react-native, expo, classnotfoundexception

Need help here, please help.
I cannot find why my app cannot run in a production release. I use **Expo Bare Workflow**

When I run **expo run:android** it succeeds and the application is built and run normally in my real device.

But when I launch to the open testing using **eas build --platform android** It creates an **aab** file. I upload it to Google Play Console. I download the apk file and install to my device. ***Then the apps crashes***.

I tried using **Test Lab Firebase** to check the issue. And this is the error provided by the **Test Lab Firebase**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.company.app.MainApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.company.app.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
       FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.company.app, PID: 26110
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.company.app.MainApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.company.app.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1268)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6690)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.company.app.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1158)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1260)
    ... 9 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:367)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:109)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:82)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:439)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:398)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:166)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:129)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:104)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:898)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:982)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1214)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2663)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2655)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6602)
        ... 8 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.en.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:367)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:109)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:82)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:439)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:398)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:166)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:129)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:104)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:898)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:982)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1214)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2663)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2655)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6602)
        ... 8 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/~~r6re0ia8oZr-bYYdxRcPtg==/com.company.app-gpnpC_W8RMut_6tG9AHRPA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:367)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:109)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:82)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:439)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:398)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:166)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:129)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:104)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:898)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:982)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1214)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2663)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2655)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6602)
        ... 8 more
```

**This is my folder structure :**

[image]

**This is my AndroidManifest.xml file :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.company.app">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL" android:value="default"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="45.0.0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@daastrading/daas-trading"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground" android:value="false"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color" android:resource="@color/white"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.company.app"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher"/>
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**This is my MainApplication.java :**

```
package com.company.app;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.config.ReactFeatureFlags;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.company.app.newarchitecture.MainApplicationReactNativeHost;

import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHostWrapper(
    this,
    new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  });

  private final ReactNativeHost mNewArchitectureNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHostWrapper(this, new MainApplicationReactNativeHost(this));

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      return mNewArchitectureNativeHost;
    } else {
      return mReactNativeHost;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the TurboModule system
    ReactFeatureFlags.useTurboModules = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.company.app.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used the latest **Expo SDK : 45** and **React-Native : 0.68.2**

I searched Google to try to find the issues related to the error. So many people got a different error related to **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** But it did not solve my problem. I cannot find the exactly same with my error in Google.
What could possible the issue to my error ?

What does the error mean ? How to fix it ? Is there something I have missed ? Because running in emulator or real device in development mode it works. My apps got pending to launch because of this issue. I have no other error.

**Thank You.**

**Note : I change all my package name to com.company.app for security reason. The real package name is like : com.testing.testing which testing is not my real package name.**

**Edit :**

This is my dependencies :

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "8.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.9.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.0",
    "accordion-collapse-react-native": "^1.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.5.0",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.6.1",
    "expo-constants": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-crypto": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.1.0",
    "expo-random": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~4.2.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-sqlite": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.13.1",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.2.1",
    "fbjs": "^3.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.7.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.15",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.12.0",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.4.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.18.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I am on "expo": "~48.0.6", "react-native": "0.71.6"
Trying to figure out what exactly is causing this. I actually tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it but none of those has worked till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem.
I don’t know exactly the solution to solve this problem.
What I did:

1. Recreate Application using “expo init testing”
2. Copy `package.json` from old to new apps.
3. Build using EAS Get the AAB file and testing it to Test Lab
   Firebase. No error.
4. Back to new apps. Copy the manifest file from old to new app.
5. Build using EAS Get the AAB file and testing it to Test Lab
   Firebase. No error.
6. Back to new app. Copy all source code to new app. Build using EAS
   Get the AAB file and testing it to Test Lab Firebase. No
   error.

And finally solved the problem. But I still don’t know what I have missed in the previous version of my app. But now it is working. So I will mark this as the solution.